# Can cultured buttermilk powder contain live cultures?

Tags: starter, buttermilk

I'm looking for some buttermilk starter, which I know I can buy online, but I wanted to shop locally first.  The two local health food stores don't carry it, so I checked one of the local supermarkets, and came across some [Saco Cultured Buttermilk Blend](http://sacofoods.com/products/view/cultured-buttermilk), which is a dry powder.  I'm curious if this can possibly contain *live* cultures, though.  One [forum post](http://www.foodrenegade.com/how-to-make-buttermilk/) I found claims it does not:

> Because the SACO buttermilk is dried, it contains no live cultures and will not be a good buttermilk starter culture.

However, many other living organisms, (such as dry yeast, and the freeze-dried Kéfir starter I found in the store today) come in dry form, so I'm not convinced that a dried product *cannot* contain live cultures, but maybe dried buttermilk is different.  So is it true that this type of product does not contain live cultures, or will it work as a buttermilk starter culture?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is true that Saco Buttermilk Blend contains no live cultures. If you can have any further questions, please feel free to call our consumer line at 1-800-373-7226. We are happy to answer any questions you may have about our product!
Amy Verheyden
Director of Consumer Affairs
Saco Foods, Inc.

Comment: Well, can't ask for a better source than that.